# Group by Week using Angular, Underscore and Moment js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, momentjs

Need some help please. I am trying to group my click stats by week using underscore and moment.

here is the code:

```
var groupedByWeekFbCompleted = _.groupBy($scope.facebookObjects, function(item) {
    return moment(item.timeclicked,"YYYY-MM-DD").isoWeek();
});
```

here is a screen shot of the chart it gives me
[image]

When I print groupedByWeekFbCompleted  to the console this is what I get
[image]

The data comes from the DB formatted like this

```
2016-06-18 14:03:56
```

I can not figure out what 24, 26, 27, 28 and 29 represent. My hope is to display the first day of the week as a label and then group by that week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will take that date string and parse it using moment you will get something like

```
moment("2016-11-08 14:03:56", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").isoWeek()
// 45
```

24, 26, 27, 28 and 29 are the week day, and the values are arrays of dates within that week

**EDIT**

To display a date string on your labels, you can use the `.format` method to parse the timestamp you get from the `moment` function, provide it the same format you used, like so:

```
moment("2016-11-08 14:03:56", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") 
// output: "2016-11-08 14:03:56"
```

Comment: If I open the object in the console.log for '24' I get  1 object and the date time for it is: 2016-06-18 14:03:56. How does '2016-06-18 14:03:56' produce 24?

Comment: `'2016-06-18 14:03:56'` happened at the 24'th week of the year (isoWeek), if you will run `moment("2016-01-07 14:03:56", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").week()` it will give 25. your function returns a number and `_.groupBy` groups your dates by these numbers

Comment: ah, that make much more sense. Do you know the best way to convert that number into an actual date for my labels?

Comment: you can use `.format` and provide that format, like this `moment("2016-11-08 14:03:56", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")`
that will give you this string `"2016-11-08 14:03:56"`

Comment: and you don't need to use the week number, it's just a property name, format the dates in the arrays